# Django count all unique accurance of a many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have models like :

```
class Book:
    author = models.ManyToManyField()

class Author:
    ...
```

I want to get all unique authors that have books.

example

BookA: AuthorA, AuthorB
BookB: AuthorB, AuthorC

Auther D, E, F has no book

so the result should be a query set of Author ABC.

Most existing answers are just count of authors of each book.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Books.objects.values_list('Author').distinct.()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the queryset with a Count to get the number of books an Author has, then filter the queryset by the annotated value:

```python
from django.db.models import Count

queryset = Author.objects.annotate(books_count=Count("book_set")).filter(
    books_count__gt=0
)
```

The approach above is great if you eventually want to change the `books_count` required. If you're sure you'll always only want to check if the user has any books at all, you can also use `book_set__isnull`:

```python
queryset = Author.objects.filter(book_set__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

@yyyyyyyan answer is perfectly fine. You can also use `Exists` subquery to do the same and more if you needed more filtering

```py
Author.objects.filter(Exists(Book.object.filter(author=OuterRef('pk')))
```